# For $f(x)=\frac {1}{x}$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x-4}$, find the domain of the composite function $g\circ f(x)$.

Tags: functions

> For $f(x)=\frac {1}{x}$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x-4}$, find the domain of the composite function $g\circ f(x)$.

**My Attempt**

Here, $$f(x)=\frac {1}{x}$$
$$g(x)=\sqrt{x-4}$$
Now,

$$g\circ f(x)=\sqrt{\frac {1-4x}{x}}$$

How can I proceed further?

Comment: Hint:  what's the domain of $g$?

Comment: $x \in (0,0.25]$

Comment: @lulu, I don't know about that.

Comment: Well...what's the domain of $h(x)=\sqrt x$?

Comment: Two hints: what *can't* you find the square root of, and when is $\dfrac{1-4x}{x}$ undefined? Whatever is outside of these two spaces is your domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$g\circ f(x)=\sqrt{f(x)-4}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-4}$$
This function is defined when $x\neq 0$ because of the $\frac{1}{x}$ and when $\frac{1}{x}-4\geq 0$ because of the $\sqrt{\quad}$. Now, if $x<0$ then $\frac{1}{x}<0$ and so $\frac{1}{x}-4<0$. Hence, we need $x>0$. Finally if $x>0$, then 
$$\frac{1}{x}-4\geq 0 \iff \frac{1}{x}\geq 4 \iff 1 \geq 4x \iff \frac{1}{4}\geq x.$$
This finally shows that the domain of $g\circ f$ is $D=(0,\frac{1}{4}]$.

Comment: The answer I have is $x=>4$

Comment: @user335710 How do you get this answer? Try to plug in $x=5$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

$$D_{gof}=\{x\in\,D_f\,|\,f(x)\in\,D_g \}$$
$D_f=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\,$, $\,D_g=[4,\infty)$ and $f(x)\in\,D_g $ was interpreted as follow
$$\frac{1}{x}\in[4,\infty)\implies \,\frac{1}{x}\ge\,4\implies \frac{1-4x}{x}\ge\,0$$
[image]

then
$$D_{gof}={R}-\{0\}\,\cap(0,\frac{1}{4}]=(0,\frac{1}{4}] $$